# After upgrade to Magento 2.2.8 my transactional email is not working anymore

Tags: magento2, email, magento-upgrade

I just updated to **Magento 2.2.8** and now my email is not working anymore, the message I get is:

> The message should be an instance of \Zend_Mail

I tried the **Mageside** and **Mageplaza** module, also without the modules this message occurs....

Comment: I too facing the same issue...How did you overcome this issue?Kindly please help me

Comment: The problem was an old version of module of SMTP mageside (that i don't use anymore), after updating that the problem was gone

Comment: But i have installed the latest version.